# Java - Sequential async executions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, jboss

I have an async task that performs database operations. This may take many minutes.

```
public void doSomeStuff() {
   // 10 minutes of database magic
}
```

Due to possible concurrency problems on the database side, there must be **only one asynchronous execution** of this method at the same time (like a singleton). Furthermore if the method is already running, the next call shall not be discarded, but **rememberered and executed when the previous call finishes**. Just like a queue.

I've researched the `@Asynchronous` and `@ConcurrencyManagement(...)` annotations, however they don't seem to provide the required control.

How can I achieve this in JavaEE 7 with the JBoss EAP 6 (+JSF)?

Comment: Mark the method synchronized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `@Stateless` bean with an `@Asynchronous` method.

Then you could set the thread pool used by the bean with the annotation `@Pool(<pool name>)`. If you limit the pool size to 1, you have what you need.